# Is hydroxylamine monodentate or ambidentate ligand?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, stereochemistry, transition-metals, cis-trans-isomerism

> What is the total number of geometric isomers of the complex $\ce{[Pt(Cl)(py)(NH3)(NH2OH)]+}$?

If $\ce{NH2OH}$ acts as an ambidentate ligand, then there should be six geometric isomers. Or is it strictly a monodentate ligand?

Comment: What did the book think?

Comment: I think I've only seen $\ce{NH2OH}$ as monodentate ligand (M−N bonding). *Deprotonated* hydroxylamines are a totally different story, there are plenty of both bi- and ambidentate complexes with those.

Comment: The title of this question doesn't match with the question in the text body. For example, hydroxyl amine acts differently with different metals. See [this](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja046724i) and [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-1693(00)95587-7) articles for examples.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne That's mostly editor's fault (mine too), not OP's. We tried to make the question less of am-I-right type and more conceptual.

Comment: I asked this question because it's a exam question, and 6 and 3 both option were present, book only has answer not explanation.